# Inserting values in to sql database

Tags: c#

I am trying to execute this statement to insert some values in to a DB.

```
com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [cars table]"
      + "([Car reg no],[MOT expiry date], Mileage,[Other information])"
      + "VALUES (" + m._INSERTCarRegNo + "," + m._INSERTExpiryDate + "," 
      + m._INSERTMileage + "," + m._INSERTotherInformation 
      + ")",this.returnConnection);
```

The above is my statement, I get an error though, the error is cannot parse the string. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to look into guarding against SQL injection. =)

Comment: You might want to look up parameterised queries as well. Your code is currently a bug fest and a potential security threat.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I lolled at "bug fest"

Comment: When you're getting an error, it's usually helpful to post the [exact error](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise) in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the quotes around the string values.

```
com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [cars table]"
  + "([Car reg no],[MOT expiry date], Mileage,[Other information])"
  + "VALUES ('" + m._INSERTCarRegNo + "','" + m._INSERTExpiryDate + "','" 
  + m._INSERTMileage + "','" + m._INSERTotherInformation 
  + "')",this.returnConnection);
```

(You don't need single quotes for number values)

Answer (score 1):

Always use `Parameters` to avoid such issues and SQL injection.

```
var sql=@"INSERT INTO [cars table] 
         ([Car reg no],[MOT expiry date], Mileage,[Other information])
          VALUES (@Carregno,@MOTexpirydate,@Mileage,@Otherinformation])";

com = new SqlCeCommand(sql,this.returnConnection);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Carregno",m._INSERTCarRegNo);
..
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a much cleaner solution (than building your own SQL strings)...

```
com = 
  new SqlCeCommand(
  "INSERT INTO [cars table] " + 
  "([Car reg no],[MOT expiry date], Mileage,[Other information] " + 
  "VALUES " + 
  "(@reg, @expiry, @mileage, @otherinfo)"
  , this.returnConnection);

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg" , m._INSERTCarRegNo);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@expiry" , m._INSERTExpiryDate);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mileage" , m._INSERTMileage);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@otherinfo" , m._INSERTotherInformation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `key,created,activations,used,hotelid)values(b,1-29-13, 3,1,11)` at line 1

Comment: the query is:-       mysql_query("insert into pins(key,created,activations,used,hotelid)values($key,$created, $actv,$usepin,$hotelid)");